# Bundling JQuery Themes Does not Seem to be Working

Tags: jquery, css, bundling-and-minification

I apologize if the answer to this question exists in the site somewhere--I did not find content that seemed to help me resolve my situation.

I am going nuts trying to figure out what I am misunderstanding about the proper implementation of jQuery and jQuery themes within an ASP.Net Web Forms 4.5 project.  I used NuGet to download JQuery, JQuery.UI.Combined, and the JQuery Flick theme.  I then tried to implement a datepicker and the flick theme is not being applied.

The NuGet download put the jQuery css base theme into Content\themes\base, and Flick theme into Content\themes\flick.

I went into the Bundle.config and added a styleBundle tag for the flick theme so it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<bundles version="1.0">
  <styleBundle path="~/Content/css">
    <include path="~/Content/Site.css" />
  </styleBundle>
  <styleBundle path="~/Content/themes/base/css">
    <include path="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css" />    
  </styleBundle>
  <styleBundle path="~/Content/themes/flick/css">
    <include path="~/Content/themes/flick/jquery.ui.flick.css" />
  </styleBundle>
</bundles>
```

I went into the Site.Master page and added this into the Placeholder tag:
        <%: Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css", "~/Content/themes/flick/css", "~/Content/css") %>

On the test page, I added the control like this:

```
    <input type="text" id="txtFromDate" style="width: 5em;" />
```

and in a script tag I have this code to run on page load:

```
    $(function () { $("#txtFromDate").datepicker(); });
```

Testing the application showed the datepicker is working but there is no style at all.  It appears on the page with the words "Previous" and "Next", followed by the name of the month and the dates; however, all the text is shown behind everything else on the page and there is no color at all.

So, what am I not understanding on how the bundling is supposed to be implemented?

C# BundleConfig Code:

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/WebFormsJs").Include(
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js",
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js",
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js",
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js",
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js",
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js",
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js",
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MsAjaxJs").Include(
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxApplicationServices.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxTimer.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js"));

        // Use the Development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you’re
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
            "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
}
```

Solution Found -- Added the following to the C# RegisterBundles() function:

```
            bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/mycss").Include(
            "~/content/site.css",
            "~/content/themes/base/accordion.css", 
            "~/content/themes/base/all.css", 
            "~/content/themes/base/autocomplete.css", 
            "~/content/themes/base/base.css", 
            "~/content/themes/base/button.css", 
            "~/content/themes/base/core.css", 
            "~/content/themes/base/datepicker.css", 
            "~/content/themes/base/dialog.css", 
            "~/content/themes/base/draggable.css", 
            "~/content/themes/base/menu.css", 
            "~/content/themes/base/progressbar.css", 
            "~/content/themes/base/resizable.css", 
            "~/content/themes/base/selectmenu.css", 
            "~/content/themes/base/slider.css", 
            "~/content/themes/base/sortable.css", 
            "~/content/themes/base/spinner.css", 
            "~/content/themes/base/tabs.css", 
            "~/content/themes/base/theme.css", 
            "~/content/themes/base/tooltip.css"));
```

Then added this to the Site.Master page:

```
<%: Styles.Render("~/mycss") %>
```

Comment: Can you show your Bundle config c# code (i.e. where you are creating the bundle from the config)?

Comment: I thought that placement of this in the Placeholder tag did just that, bundled the files and downloaded them: <%: Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css", "~/Content/themes/flick/css", "~/Content/css") %>.  Is that not true?

Comment: I added the solution code to the original post.  Thanks @trueblueaussie for pointing me in the correct direction.   Also thanks to Dino Esposito for this article: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn451436.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn451436.aspx)